# java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format while encrypting and decrypting a file using RSA with symmetrics Key in Java

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes, rsa

I am doing a project to learn about encryption and decryption. I encrypt a file (input file) and encrypt the symmetric key using RSA public. Then I decrypt the symmetric key using RSA private key and then decrypt the file(output file).

here below is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class Main {
    public static SecretKey generateKey(int n) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(n);
        SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        return key;
    }
    public static IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
        byte[] iv = new byte[128/8];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
        return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    }

    public static void encryptFile(String algorithm, SecretKey key, IvParameterSpec iv,
                                   File inputFile, File outputFile) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byte[] output = cipher.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            if (output != null) {
                outputStream.write(output);
            }
        }
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal();
        if (outputBytes != null) {
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public static void decryptFile(String algorithm, SecretKey key, IvParameterSpec iv,
                                   File inputFile, File outputFile) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byte[] output = cipher.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            if (output != null) {
                outputStream.write(output);
            }
        }
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal();
        if (outputBytes != null) {
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }


    public static byte[] encryptSymmetricKey(SecretKey secKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        byte[] key = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("publicKey.key"));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(key);
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY, publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(secKey.getEncoded());
        return encryptedKey;
    }

    public static SecretKey decryptSymmetricKey(SecretKey secKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        byte[] encryptedKey= encryptSymmetricKey(secKey);
        byte[] key = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("publicKey.key"));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key);
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
        byte[] decryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(encryptedKey);
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKey , 0, decryptedKey .length, "AES");
        return originalKey;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, RuntimeException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

        SecretKey secKey=generateKey(128);
        IvParameterSpec iv=generateIv();

        File inputFile=new File("C:/Users/nm-ca/IdeaProjects/RSA/src/inputFile.txt");
        File outputFile=new File("C:/Users/nm-ca/IdeaProjects/RSA/src/outputFile.txt");
        encryptFile("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding",secKey,iv,inputFile,outputFile);


        //Decrypt the cipher text using decrypted symmetric key
        decryptFile("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", decryptSymmetricKey(secKey),iv,outputFile,inputFile);
    }
}
```

The Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format

When I encrypt the symmetric key and then decrypt it, I produce an invalid key I guess. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Decryption must be performed with the private key (belonging to the public key used for encryption), not with the public key, see [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

Comment: And as the first step `KeyFactory.generatePrivate` only works on the private key not the public one, hence the method name. And more specifically a private key in PKCS8 unencrypted format (hence the class name `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`) -- while things other than Java often use the "X.509" format for a public key (when not in a certificate), for a private key quite a few different formats are used that are not supported by Java standardly (you need a third-party library like bouncycastle).